# ¿Cómo puedo declarar una variable php para usarlo en una cookie?

Tags: php, html, function, cookies

Tengo ya unos días probando hacer este trabajo, y no he logrado que las cookies me funcionen, suele salir así[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código, espero me puedan ayudar a resolverlo, estoy haciéndo un inicio de sesión donde se guarde la sesión con las cookies, y mi problema es tal cual que al mostrar la cookie diga Bienvenido + usuario de la base de datos. Pero siempre suelta el puro código.

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<?php


$userphp = "user";
//echo $passphp;
?>

<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
function getCookie(cname){
var name = cname + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++ ){
var c = ca[i];
while (c.charAt(0)== ''){
c = c.substring(1);}
if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
}
}
return "";
}
function checkCookie() 
{
  var aux = getCookie("user");
  if (aux == "" || aux == null) 
  {
  window.location.replace("/login.php");
    
  } 
}
function setCookie(nombre,valor,caducidad) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (caducidad*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
  document.cookie = nombre + "=" + valor + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

</SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
// Mostramos las cookies
alert("Bienvenido" + document.cookie );
</SCRIPT>

</HEAD>
<BODY onload="checkCookie()" bgcolor=8FFFFF>
<script type="text/javascript">

setCookie("user","<?php echo $user; ?>",5);

</script>
Formulario para Agregar un nuevo usuario
<BR>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="get" action="base.php">
<BR>Nombre: <BR>
<input name="campo1" id="campo1" type="text"/>
<BR>Apellido:<BR>
<input name="campo2" id="campo2" type="text"/>
<BR>User:<BR>
<input name="campo3" id="campo3" type="text"/>
<BR>Pass:<BR>
<input name="campo4" id="campo4" type="text"/><BR><BR>
<input name="boton1" id="boton1" type="submit" value="Enviar"/> 
</form>


Formulario para Eliminar un usuario, ingrese el id a eliminar:
<BR>
<BR>
<form id="form2" name="form2" method="get" action="Eliminar.php"> 
<input name="campo3" id="campo3" type="text"/>
<input name="boton2" id="boton2" type="submit" value="Eliminar"/>
</form>
<BR>



<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">



</SCRIPT>


</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: No es conveniente usar cookies con Javascript para el manejo de sesiones, porque se ejecuta en el navegador, mientras que PHP se ejecuta en el servidor y la comunicación entre ambos no es tan sencilla. No encontré aquí material suficiente para ayudarte, pero puedes leer esto: http://www.forosdelweb.com/f18/aporte-seguridad-basica-php-1011808/#post4265381

Comment: Gracias Igualmente, lo leeré.

Answer (score 0):

quítale las comillas al *setCookie*, que quede así:

```
setCookie("user", <?php echo $user; ?> , 5);
```

Con las comillas estarías pasando una cadena de texto y por eso te muestra `Bienvenidouser=<?php echo $user; ?>`

Y como comenta el compañero arriba, es mejor usar variables de sesión en vez de cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Incluso si no optas por variables de sesión, puedes crear la galleta desde PHP:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<?php 
  $caducidad = 1; // 1 día
  setcookie( 'user', 'usuario', time()+$caducidad*24*60*60*1000, '/' ); 
?>
```

Y así no reinventas la rueda con tu función `setCookie()` en javascript.